# ISERROR MATCH multiple result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have my own input data on column A and on column B I need to check whether they're match with data in another worksheet named 'database' by iserror formula

```
=ISERROR(MATCH([@POLICYNO],database!$M:$M,0))
```

when they're match value in database sheet column B return FALSE if not return TRUE which's totally fine.

but the problem is if I need to expand the database. not only on column M. I try to use

```
=ISERROR(MATCH([@POLICYNO],database!$M:$N,0))
```

or

```
=ISERROR(OR(MATCH([@POLICYNO],filter!$M:$M,0),MATCH([@POLICYNO],filter!$N:$N,0)))
```

both are wrong because it show all TRUE for all policyno which is not

how can i fix it?
Thank you so much!

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 1):

If you post few sample data then we can suggest better solution for you. With your current formula you can try-

```
=ISERROR(IFERROR(MATCH([@POLICYNO],database!$M:$M,0),MATCH([@POLICYNO],database!$N:$N,0)))
```

If you version have `XLOOKUP()` then you can handle the situation by nested `XLOOKUP()` function.